# How do I wrap the results of a command in quotes to pass it to another command?

Tags: macos, firefox, for-loop, sed, find

This is for the Apple platform. My end goal is to do a find and replace for a line inside of the firefox preference file "prefs.js" to turn off updates. I want to be able to do this for all accounts on the Mac, including the user template (didn't include that in the examples). So far I've been able to get a list of all the paths that have the prefs.js file with this:

```
find /Users -name prefs.js
```

I then put the old preference and new preference in variables:

```
oldPref='user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);'
newPref='user_pref("app.update.enabled", true);'
```

I then have a "for loop" with the sed command to replace the old preference with the new preference:

```
for prefs in `find /Users -name prefs.js`
  do
  sed "s/$oldPref/$newPref/g" "$prefs"
done
```

The problem I'm running into is that the "find" command returns the full paths with the stupid "Application Support" in the path name like this:

```
/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/437cwg3d.default/prefs.js
```

When the command runs, I get these errors:

```
sed: /Users/admin/Library/Application: No such file or directory
sed: Support/Firefox/Profiles/437cwg3d.default/prefs.js: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming that I somehow need to get the "find" command to wrap the outputted path in quotes for the "sed" command to parse it correctly? I'm I on the right path? I've tried to pipe the find command into sed to wrap quotes, but I can't get anything to work correctly. Please let me know if I should go about this differently. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to `for prefs in ...` on a list of files that are output from `find`.  For a more complete explanation of why this is bad, see [Greg's wiki page about parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You would only use a for loop in bash if you could match the files using a glob, which is difficult if you want to do it recursively.

It would be better, if you can swing it, to use `find ... -exec ...` instead.  Perhaps something like:

```
find /Users -name prefs.js -exec sed -i.bak -e "s/$oldPref/$newPref/" {} \;
```

The `sed` command line is executed once for each file found by `find`.  The `{}` gets replaced with the filename.  Sed's `-i` option lets you run it in-place, rather than requiring stdin/stdout.  Check the man page for usage details.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I'm still learning something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

(Grain of salt: I'm basing this on my experience with linux)

I think it less to do with sed and more to do with the way the for loop array is formed. When the the results of find are converted to an array, the space between Application and Support is treated as a delimiter.

There are several ways to work around this, but the easiest is probably to change the IFS variable. The IFS variable is an internal variable that your command line interpreter uses to separate fields ([more info](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)). You can change the IFS variable of the environment before running the find command.

Modified example from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for f in `find /Users -name prefs.js`
do
  echo "$f"
done
# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```